# Java - Android - How to programmatically hide or show controls using ID

Tags: java, android

I don't have my source code right now, but I was wondering if it is possible to use visibility(GONE) with the ID's or something like that?

The reason : I have a form where I want to have 20 dropdowns, and a button "add a new activity" . When  you click on the button, it unhide a new control. The problem is in how to tell the app what dropdown to unhide...

Example :

dropdown1 (visible)         [Button add new]

dropdown2 (invisible)

dropdown3 (invisible)
[...]

---

user click on [Button Add new]

dropdown1 (visible)

dropdown2 (visible)

dropdown3 (invisible)
[...]

---

Or something similar in process.

Thanks! (sorry not english speaking person... I hope this is understandable as a question!)

Answer (score 1):

In **xml** give id to all `spinner` (Dropdown) like `drop1`,`drop2`,...........

like this

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/drop1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>
```

In **Java** file add

```
Spinner drop1,drop2,............drop20;
```

Under `onCreate` Method

```
drop1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop1);
drop2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop2);

--------------------------------------
drop20 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop20);
```

Set **Visibility**

```
if(condition)         // your condition to hide dropdown
{
drop1.setVisibility(Visible.GONE);
}
else
{
drop1.setVisibility(Visible.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After mapping the control you can use setVisibility() method with it

eg:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setVisibility(View.Visible);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Using `android:id` tag in `XML` layout.

In your Java code you can do it like this:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById('button1');
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById('button2');
       buton1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                     button2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            }
        } );
```